# change woocommerce "select options" button (link it to a single product page)

Tags: woocommerce

it's been 3 weeks i'm facing this problem but still couldn't find any solution. Maybe anyone of you guys can provide me a solution. I want to change the link of "select options" button (as in picture 1). Now, when we click on the "select options" button, it will display a lightbox (as in picture 2). I dont want the lightbox, I want it to be redirected to a single product page (as in picture 3). Hope anyone can provide me with a solution. Thank you.

see image
[image: image for reference]

Answer (score 0):

go to theme settings> shop settings> product archive> disable lightbox